# JFileChooser - How to fix "Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!"

Tags: java, runtime-error, windows-10, jfilechooser

When I try to run the following java program, or anything involving a JFileChooser

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
        choose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int approve=choose.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(approve==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File file = choose.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error below:

`Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!`

The program works as intended, with the JFileChooser showing up in a window and displaying the file path after selection, however the error message is still outputted to the console, often multiple times. No other information regarding this error is given. I am running the latest version of Windows 10 and Java jdk 8u66. The error occurs both when running from Eclipse and from java through command prompt. I have tried restarting the system, uninstalling and reinstalling Java, and trying an older version of Java. In addition, I do not have Qt installed on my system. I have tried searching up this problem and have found no helpful results. How can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: I believe this is just a warning and not error. Update your windows from QT version. Perhaps to 5.5.

Comment: As I had stated before, I did not have Qt installed on the system, nor had I ever had it or used it before. Since the time I have asked the question, I have also tried installing the latest version of Qt (5.5.1) and then running the program from both Eclipse and command prompt. I have also tried it again after uninstalling Qt. None of these attempts have achieved any solutions. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with Java. It's more related to windows.

Comment: As it happens when you are opening a file chooser, I guess that some component in your computer - that has nothing to do with your application - might have installed something related to network drives which now is activated when your program launches the file chooser. You should try and search your system for installed version of the qt library to find the culprit.